# Which one would be better to a members website, Joomla or Drupal

Tags: drupal, joomla

Or maybe other OS cms?

I want to form a members website, with registration, member profile and member personal photo galleries

What would you suggest? I'm pretty advanced with PHP just don't have the time to develop from scratch

Comment: Of course I mean by using plugins/modules

Answer (score 4):

I don't know much about Drupal but if you're using Joomla you may need to install something like [Community Builder](http://www.joomlapolis.com/) and/or [Simple ACL](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/access-a-security/frontend-access-control/4836). Joomla's default user management isn't great.

Comment: Joomla 1.6 is working out in ACL. There are some alpha builds being released with ACL features - but yes, the user's default management in stable versions isn't great.

Comment: Funny enough I tried the 1.6 alpha the other day; it's a long way off being ready. The devs are saying 4-6 months.

Answer (score 4):

Drupal does what you are asking from a basic install with quite a degree of fine grained control over members, profiles, permissions etc. I have set several up with little or no extra modules, plugins or programming.

I actually run one site with several hundred members with not problems. I am not saying you cannot do this with Joomla, just have not had the experience. I think Drupal may well be more "community" oriented in this respect.

Answer (score 1):

I vote for Drupal. Even Obama [has voted](http://techpresident.com/blog-entry/why-white-houses-embrace-drupal-matters-0) for Drupal.

Comment: As much as I love Drupal, I doubt Obama himself had anything to do with that decision.

Answer (score 1):

Joomla and Community Builder / JomSocial should be a nice pair.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, Drupal is far more flexible than Joomla. If you're comfortable with PHP, I'd recommend picking it.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely Drupal, especially if you already know advanced PHP.

Nobody has great user features out of the box, but Drupal has more and better quality user-related modules.

Look at drupalmodules.com for 'user' modules in the 6.x versions, and you'll see tons of related modules for each one you check out.

There are modules for advanced profiles, for a percentage (of the profile) completed, user badges to make them feel special, imagecache for excellent image support, image upload with cropping, ckk and views can setup many different kinds of photo galleries from scratch so they are completely customized for your site, ubercart if you want to sell premium memberships, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I think both Drupal and Joomla would be able to handle creating a basic version of what you describe. The turning point is going to be, what more you want to do.

One of Drupal's strengths is first truely uncovered when you develop. You can very easily customize the look and feel of your Drupal site. You'll have more fine grained control of both what it does and what how it outputs it's markup etc. It's a powerful tool, only downside is that it can be a bit hard to understand for normal people. But  knowing PHP that shouldn't be a hindrance to you.

Answer (score 0):

I already created 2 Drupal Sites and 1 Joomla Site with this Feature. 
Since I've worked with Joomla some years too, I think I can give you some Hints on it:

Drupal is WAY more flexible and professional than Joomla. But you have to put some effort into it. But if you know how to use it, it will do what you want. And since Drupal itself is so flexible the core does handle almost every feature you need. So it is possible to mix a lot of features together and do things nobody has thinked of before.

If you use Joomla, you have to pick a module for this task (like CommunityBuilder http://www.joomlapolis.com/) and while this module is very powerful, it may work together with other modules, but likely it will not.